# Trying to make a program that searches for an inputted word in another input

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vb.net-2010

```
 Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim words As Int64=0
    Dim dictionary As String()
    Dim Input1 As String
    Dim CurrentWord As String
    dictionary=New String() {}
    Input1=richTextBox1.text + (" ")
    Dim n As Int64=5

    For c = 1 To Len(Input1)
        If Mid(Input1,c,1) <> (" ") Then
            CurrentWord = CurrentWord & Mid(Input1,c,1)
        Else
            words=words+1
            **dictionary(n)=CurrentWord**
        End If

        richTextBox3.Text=("words is " & words & "current words is " & CurrentWord)
    Next        

End Sub
```

This is what I have so far, The main problem seems to be with the line dictionary(n)=CurrentWord . If anyone has any ideas / existing program that acheives the same goal I would be really greatful. Thanks!

Also It is coming up with the following error message if this helps
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: vba is not vb.net and vice versa.  I have removed the vba tag as this seems to be vb.net.

Comment: Arrays need to be allocated with the correct dimension before inserting any element. You don't initialize your array. However try to use a List(Of String) instead of an array with a dimension. By the way, have you ever looked at string.Split method?

Comment: How do I initialise an array/ make a list. Sorry, I'm a bit new to this as you can tell

Comment: Cheers Blackwood, I really appreciate that! I don't mean to be rude, but do you have any suggestions for searching for an inputted word in an inputted text?

Comment: I edited my answer to include simple code to check whether a given word was found. If you have more comments about my answer, please post them as comments on my answer rather than your question. That makes it easier for me to see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the code by using the `String.Split` method to split the text into an array of words, and the array's `Length` property to count the number of words.

```
Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim dictionary() As String = richtextbox1.Text.Split(" "c)
    Dim words As Int64 = dictionary.Length
End Sub
```

[In response to a comment asking how to check to see if a word is found].

You can use the`Contains` method to see if the array contains a given word. For example:

```
Dim searchword As String = "someword"
If dictionary.Contains(searchword) Then
    MessageBox.Show(searchword & " was found")
End If
```

If you are using a version of the .Net Framework that is older than version 3.5, you can use the `IndexOf` method (at least Framework 2.0 and later) like this:

```
Dim searchword As String = "someword"
If Array.IndexOf(dictionary, searchword) >= 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show(searchword & " was found")
End If
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for all the work you've done. If you dont mind, it is saying that '.Contains' isn't part of the system Array. I assume that means I have an outdated version. How can I use the same premise as .Contains but on 4.4 sharp develop.

Comment: @JamesGreen I believe `Contains` should work with .Net Framework 3.5 (which I think you can target with SharpDevelop 4.4) or later. If you are using an older version, you can replace that statement with `If Array.IndexOf(dictionary, searchword) >= 0 Then`.

Comment: You have no idea how helpful that is. I really hate to keep asking you things but do you know a way that I can display the word's position, e.g. the word 'hello' appears the 5th letter in?

Comment: @JamesGreen `Array.IndexOf` returns the position of the word in the array (0 = 1st word, 1 = 2nd word, and so on). So use something like `Dim wordNumber as Integer = Array.IndexOf(dictionary, searchword) + 1`. You will still need to check if `IndexOf` returns -1 or `wordNumber = 0 in order to see if the word was found.